# Unicode string Python

Tags: python, unicode

I need to write to a file a string that contains the degree sign (°).

This string is stored in variable and, as expected, when I try: `f.write(myVariable.encode('utf-8'))` I get UnicodeDecodeError.

If I try to write this string to a file like:

```
x = u'aaa°°bbb'
f.write(encode(x))
```

works fine, but I can't write `x = u'aaa°°bbb'` in my code because `'aaa°°bbb'` comes from a data base and it is stored in a variable and if I try `newVar = unicode(myVariable)` i get `UnicodeDecodeError`.

I would need to pass myVariable to the 'u' python operator... How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Decode it after retrieving it, using whatever encoding your database uses.

```
s.decode('latin1')
```

Of course, if it's misencoded in the database in the first place then you'll need to compensate somehow.

```
s.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on if your `myVariable` is in unicode or bytes format (different naming in py2 and py3), you have to decide on conversion.

As `newVar = unicode(myVariable)` fails to decode, you probably are in bytes format (`str()` in py2). So you either have to convince your database to talk in Unicode with you, or you have to know the encoding and decode it according to that.

Answer (score 1):

If `myVariable` is a string that comes from an external source (like a database), you first need to find out what *kind* of string it is.

Since you seem to be using python2, there are two main possibilities: `myVariable` is either a *unicode* string object, or a *bytes* string object. A unicode string is one that has already been *decoded* to text characters. A bytes string is one that has already been *encoded* (using an encoding like 'utf-8' or 'latin-1').

It appears from the example code in your question that `myVariable` is a *bytes* string object.

The reason you get the first `UnicodeDecodeError` is because you are trying to *re*-encode a byte string. To do this, python would first have to *decode* `myVariable` to a unicode string object before it could apply the new encoding. By default, python assumes an "ascii" encoding when automatically decoding in this way - but since `myVariable` contains bytes beyond the ascii range (0-128), an error occurs.

The same situation occurs when you try to pass `myVariable` to the `unicode` function. Unless an explicit encoding is given, python will again assume "ascii", and you will see the same `UnicodeDecodeError`.

Now, when it comes to writing `myVariable` to a file, the solution is very simple if it is a bytes string object: do nothing! Just write `myVariable` directly to the file:

```
f = open(path, 'wb')
f.write(myVariable)
f.close()
```

However, when you read the file back, you *will* need to know the original encoding of `myVariable` in order to decode it to unicode:

```
f = open(path)
myVariable = f.read().decode('utf-8')
f.close()
```

And now if you modify `myVariable` and want to write it back out to file again, you have to remember that this time it is a *unicode* string, and so you need to encode it first:

```
f = open(path, 'wb')
f.write(myVariable.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the file as text using [`codecs.open()`](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html) with UTF-8 encoding and write Unicode string without manually encoding them, it's easier and the code looks better.

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`  at the top of your python file. It should encode seamlessly